# Cluster encounters unknown issues after launching AzureML job

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am encountering this error on different GPU clusters after launching the job.

```
Run requested 1 node(s). 'cluster_name' cluster has encountered unknown issue. Please check the cluster status or try resubmitting to another cluster.
```

[image]

I create a GPU compute instance through the AzureML GUI.  I've tried this with different environments, as well and get the same error.

Including the AzureML cli and sdk code to run this.

File structure

```
- cloud
   docker
     Dockerfile
   environment.yaml
   job.yaml
- src
   test.py
```

My `environment.yaml` file

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/environment.schema.json
name: test_env
build:
  path: docker
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/aifx/acpt/stable-ubuntu2004-cu117-py38-torch201:biweekly.202310.1.v2

RUN pip install transformers
```

`job.yaml`

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/commandJob.schema.json

type: command
description: Test downloading Bart model through HF.
experiment_name: "test_job"
compute: azureml:compute_name

code: ../src
environment: azureml:test_env:1
command: python test.py
```

test.py

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM

def main():
    device = 'cuda'
    checkpoint2 = "facebook/bart-large"
    # this doesn't
    bart = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint2, trust_remote_code=True).to(device)

    print(type(bart))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The environment builds successfully after I launch this from the command line (after setting the default workspace and resource group): 
`az ml environment create -f cloud/environment.yaml`

I then launch the job 
`az ml job create -f cloud/job.yaml`